# How to prevent from getting spammed in a contact form

Tags: forms, advertising

I have the captcha image module and an email address keeps spamming me in a website feedback contact form.  I do not know how to get their IP address and I do not want to take down the form for the public.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

That is why Mollom exists: http://drupal.org/project/mollom

> Mollom may block a post outright if it is from a known spammer. If
>   Mollom is unsure how to classify a post, it may require the completion
>   of a CAPTCHA to accept the post. Posts that do not match a "spammy"
>   text pattern and do not originate from known spammers are accepted
>   without the need to complete a CAPTCHA.
>
> A stand-alone CAPTCHA solution, which neither considers user behavior
>   nor point of origin, can never achieve this level of informed
>   protection, and generally requires users to solve a CAPTCHA on every
>   post. Using Mollom's text analysis, users must only solve CAPTCHAs
>   when Mollom is unsure about a post.

Comment: Mollom no longer exists.

Answer (score 2):

Try the [reCAPTCHA](http://drupal.org/project/recaptcha) module.  It's worked brilliantly for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can try out the [Honeypot](http://drupal.org/project/honeypot) module.  It basically adds a hidden field to your forms, and then makes sure it is empty upon submission.